# Does `git reset HEAD~2` work the same as running twice `git reset HEAD`?

Tags: git

Does

```
git reset HEAD~2
```

work the same as running twice

```
git reset HEAD
```

?

In the second way,  the output of `git log` doesn't change before and after i run `git reset HEAD` for the second time, as if the second run of `git reset HEAD` doesn't do anything.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean `git reset HEAD~1` or `git reset HEAD^` in that second example? Because otherwise, no, it is not the same at all.

Comment: I forgot that. Thanks. @Lasse

Answer (score 2):

`git reset HEAD~2` means to go back last two commits.

`git reset HEAD` means to go back to last commit (discard all local changes that are not committed yet).